# WordPress Change Site Language option

Tags: wordpress

In the latest Wordpress version 4.1 you should be able to change language by visiting:

Settings > General : Change Site Language option value.

Language can be selected from a list of available languages.

but i can only find English language is there anyway to upload Arabic language also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Arabic language also requires a RTL (right-to-left) template, so you would need to install a plugin for that.

Do you want to switch the administration section to Arabic or just the frontend template?

I have successfully used this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/arabic-font/ - for several posts and pages.

Comment: I only need Arabic for just the front end template

Comment: Then you need to create an Arabic template. I have just checked my website and I have the arabic language. It's the first one below English. Can you post a screenshot with your languages?

Comment: i fix it i download Arabic WordPress and make two websites thanks a lot